# Dynamic change protractor-result folder 'protractor-html-screenshot-reporter'

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor

Here is my conf.js file.

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

var reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
      dest                    : '/opt/src/protractor/results/',
      filename                : 'index.html',
      showSummary             : true,
      showQuickLinks          : true,
      showConfiguration       : true,
      cleanDestination        : true,
      ignoreSkippedSpecs      : false,
      reportOnlyFailedSpecs   : false,
      captureOnlyFailedSpecs  : true,
});

exports.config = {

      ...


      // Setup the report before any tests start
      beforeLaunch: function() {
            return new Promise(function(resolve){
                  reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
            });
      },


      onPrepare: function () {          

            reporter.dest = '/opt/src/protractor/results/' + browser.params.directory + '/'; 

            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
```

I would like to dynamicly change the destination directory by passing arguments :
Eg :

```
protractor conf.js --suite=MySuiteName --browser.params.directory=MyDirectory
```

All reports are generated in `/opt/src/protractor/results/` instead of `/opt/src/protractor/results/MyDirectory`

Why I can't change Destination directory?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter` implement, it only read the destination folder by `options.dest` of the passed-in `options` when call `new HtmlScreenshotReporter(options)`.

Thus changing `reporter.dest` won't change the destination folder when generate report files

Please try below code: (delay to init reporter instance in `onPrepare`, in which you can get the value of CLI argument: `--browser.params.directory`

```
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');

var reportOpts = {
      dest                    : '/opt/src/protractor/results/',
      filename                : 'index.html',
      showSummary             : true,
      showQuickLinks          : true,
      showConfiguration       : true,
      cleanDestination        : true,
      ignoreSkippedSpecs      : false,
      reportOnlyFailedSpecs   : false,
      captureOnlyFailedSpecs  : true,
};

var reporter;

exports.config = {

    onPrepare: function () {          

        // change reporter destination
        reportOpts.dest = '/opt/src/protractor/results/' + browser.params.directory + '/'; 

        // delay init reporter instance in onPrepare(), but beforelaunch()
        reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter(reportOpts);

        reporter.beforeLaunch(function(){
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);
        });
    },

    // Close the report after all tests finish
    afterLaunch: function(exitCode) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve){
            reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
        });
    }
};
```